# how to create\start a thread with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I use ThreadStart to create\start a thread with method parameters.

```
private void GenerateData(Type Method){
   ThreadStart tStart = null;
   tStart = new ThreadStart(Method);
   Thread t = new Thread(tStart);
   t.Start();
}

private void DoWork{
   //code processing here
}


// I want to call thread like this
private void rundata(){
    GenerateData(Dowork);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a parameter of type `Type` called `Method`? I could understand `Type type` or `MethodInfo method`, but `Type Method` makes no sense... it's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* just want:

```
private void GenerateData(ThreadStart method)
{
    Thread thread = new ThreadStart(method);
    thread.Start();
}
```

You could then certainly have:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    ...
}

private void RunData()
{
    GenerateData(DoWork);
}
```

... although given how trivial `GenerateData` is, I'm not sure it's really worth it... you could just have:

```
private void RunData()
{
    new Thread(DoWork).Start();
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to use Thread(DoWork).Start(); I want to use it as function so that, i can call it to use anywhere i want. please help me...... thanks.

Comment: @RithUdom: Well I've already shown you how you can do it, at the start of the answer...